# Return true if string contains a long (+10 digits) number

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I would like to check if the provided string contains a number with more than ten digits.

```
exampleString = aaa123aaa12345aaaa   <--- not true
exampleString = 12345678   <--- not true
exampleString = 1234567,12345,123345   <--- not true
exampleString = aaaa12345678901234aaaa124aaa <-- true
```

I was trying to do something like extracting numbers to individual strings and then check if their length > 10, but I was unsuccesfull.

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: [regexp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts)?

Comment: You can use the `Len` Function for each element on the String and verify if is number `IsNumeric()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a simple [Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/like-operator)?

```
if str like "*###########*" then ...
```

Comment: Should be 11 `#`

Comment: Perfect! How the hell I didn't hear about Like operator before? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
Function IsMore10Digits(strVal)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "\d{11,}": IsMore10Digits = .Test(strVal)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Shorter version :)

Comment: @ShaiRado Definitely ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using `RegEx` object:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestReg()

' sub to test RegEx10Digits function

Dim exampleString   As String

exampleString = "aaaa12345678901234aaaa124aaa"
MsgBox RegEx10Digits(exampleString)

End Sub
```

---

```
Function RegEx10Digits(RegString As String) As Boolean

' RegEx variables
Dim Reg As Object
Dim RegMatches As Variant

RegEx10Digits = False

Set Reg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With Reg
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "\d{11,}" ' Match any set of 10+  digits
End With

Set RegMatches = Reg.Execute(RegString)
If RegMatches.Count >= 1 Then ' make sure there is at least 1 match
    RegEx10Digits = True
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Why there's still `{10,}`? :(

Comment: Oops! 11 again)